# Rails: how to render nested form in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

For example, I have two models:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :task_details
end

class TaskDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :task
end
```

I want to display a table, each row in table is one TaskDetail and allow user input. After that user submits, all data will put to server. Here is my code:
(Note that: I `@data[:task]` is a task object because I want to return a hash with some information for view)

```
<%= form_for @data[:task], :url => tasks_path do |f| %>
    <table> ... </table>
<% end %>
```

My question is: How can I do as my requirement.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your `Task` model has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_details` and then you can do something like...

```
<%= form_for @data[:task], :url => tasks_path do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Task Name</th>
      <th>Task Description</th>
    <tr>
    <%= f.fields_for :task_details do |task_detail| %>
      <tr>
        <%= task_detail.hidden_field :id %>
        <td><%= task_detail.text_field :name %></td>
        <td><%= task_detail.text_field :description %> </td>
      <tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>    
<% end %>
```

Note the use of the hidden field for `:id` ... you need that so that rails can distinguish data from existing tasks versus a new task you're entering.

In your `new` method you should ensure there's at least one `new` task detail to provide an empty line on the form to input the detail

```
def new
  ...
  @data[:task].task_details.build
  ...
end
```

Comment: thanks. at each `<tr>` I have one loop. so how can I make `field_for` run only one time with already known index

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you saying that your `Task` object only has one `TaskDetail` object?  Then the loop will only display once.

Are you talking about displaying many different types of task details and the user selects one?

Comment: Maybe you should clearly explain with examples what you're trying to achieve.